# Javascript foreach array key values, output to html

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

How do I loop thru array keys to output their values to HTML?

The layout I'm working with is a thumbnail grid, 3 columns by 2 rows.  Each thumbnail has a caption below it.  Selecting any of the thumbnails opens up a hidden container which is also a grid of 3 columns and 2 rows.  Within that hidden container many of the images and captions are going to be identical so rather than have a whole bunch of duplicate HTML I figured I could just store each in an array and reference the values that each is associated with.  I'm just stuck on how to create the loop at the moment.

```
var img=[
    'image01.jpg','image02.jpg','image03.jpg','image04.jpg'
]
var details=[
    'aaaaaa','bbbbbb','cccccc','dddddd'
];

$( "#yin" ).click(function() {
    var img = [0,2];        
    var details = [0,1];

    $(step).each(function() {
        document.getElementById("img").innerHTML();
    });
    $(imgs).each(function() {
        document.getElementById("img").innerHTML();
    });
});


<div class="container">
    <ul class="row-fluid">
        <li class="span4" id="yin">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <img src="yin.jpg" />
                <h3>Yin</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span4" id="yang">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <img src="yang.jpg" />
                <h3>Yang</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="show-details details">
                <div class="detail-content">

                    <div id="img">
                    <!-- Loop (for yin would be image01, and image03) -->
                    </div>
                    <div id="details">
                    <!-- Loop (for yin would be 'aaaaaa','bbbbbb') -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The description isn't very clear. At least to me. What does that have to do with looping through keys? Your code doesn't have a loop in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue with that code before you get into looping, the `img` and `details` variables are being re-declared inside your click function. What are they intended to be? From the comments in your code they seem to be specifying which indices of the array to use.

```
var images = ['image01.jpg','image02.jpg','image03.jpg','image04.jpg'];
var details = ['aaaaaa','bbbbbb','cccccc','dddddd'];

$( "#yin" ).click(function() {
    var imgIndices = [0,2];
    var detailIndices = [0,1];

    $("#img").html("");
    $("#details").html("");

    $(imgIndices).each(function(i, o) {
        $("#img").append("<img src=\"" + images[o] + "\"/>");
    });
    $(detailIndices).each(function(i, o) {
        $("#details").append("<p>" + details[o] + "</p>");
    });
});


<div class="container">
    <ul class="row-fluid">
        <li class="span4" id="yin">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <img src="yin.jpg" />
                <h3>Yin</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span4" id="yang">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <img src="yang.jpg" />
                <h3>Yang</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="show-details details">
                <div class="detail-content">

                    <div id="img">
                    <!-- Loop (for yin would be image01, and image03) -->
                    </div>
                    <div id="details">
                    <!-- Loop (for yin would be 'aaaaaa','bbbbbb') -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would take the click function out to a named function though and just pass in the arrays.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Sorry I wasn't sure quite how to phrase my question.